# SVG smaller than specified

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to display an external svg file using the use tag.

**index.html**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32px" height="32px">
    <use href="./Assets/svg/icons/house.svg#bsi-house"></use>
</svg>
```

**house.svg**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <symbol viewbox="0 0 32 32" id="bsi-house">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 13.5V7h1v6.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h9a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V7h1v6.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2 13.5zm11-11V6l-2-2V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.293 1.5a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0l6.647 6.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 2.207 1.354 8.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L7.293 1.5z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

I expected the svg to fill the 32x32px viewport, but it was smaller than 32x32px:
[image: SVG result]

How can I draw a 32x32px svg?

Comment: You will need to use a different viewBox for the symbol like`viewbox="0 0 15 15"`. In order to unserstand what happens you can draw a rect inside the symbol with width and height = 32.

Comment: I followed your advice and was able to draw a 32px*32px square, but the problem persisted.
If I write directly to the svg it is fine, but if I load an external file the icon remains small.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-resonance-xn47z?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

As [@enxaneta points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141685/svg-smaller-than-specified#comment123990321_70141685), the problem is that the symbol's viewbox specifies a 32x32 canvas but the paths draw a 15px icon. Either reduce the viewbox to the bounds of the icon or change the paths to use the entire 32x32 grid.

```css
#symbols {
  display: none;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="symbols">
  <!-- original, with 32x32 viewbox -->
  <symbol viewbox="0 0 32 32" id="bsi-house-32">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 13.5V7h1v6.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h9a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V7h1v6.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2 13.5zm11-11V6l-2-2V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.293 1.5a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0l6.647 6.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 2.207 1.354 8.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L7.293 1.5z"/>
  </symbol>
  
  <!-- 15x15 viewbox to be closer to the icon's actual bounding box -->
  <symbol viewbox="0 0 15 15" id="bsi-house-15">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 13.5V7h1v6.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h9a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V7h1v6.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2 13.5zm11-11V6l-2-2V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.293 1.5a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0l6.647 6.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 2.207 1.354 8.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L7.293 1.5z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32px" height="32px">
  <use href="#bsi-house-32"></use>
</svg>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32px" height="32px">
  <use href="#bsi-house-15"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: I understand your advice. But the problem is when I load the svg file from outside. I have set the viewbox to 15x15 as in the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-resonance-xn47z?file=/house.svg), but it remains small. Am I making a big mistake?